# Is there a way to transform specific keywords to uppercase on save with JSON?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there's a way to transform a specific keyword to uppercase when saving a file in vsCode with JSON. (my intention is for SQL)

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {"editor.action.transformToUppercase": ["select", "from",...]}
```

Of course the example above is not correct, cause `editor.action.transformToUppercase` accepts boolean only, but it's only to get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an extension that could be of help to you: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  The commands you create in settings can be used in a `codeAction`.

You can create a command (in `settings.json`) like:

```
"findInCurrentFile": {
  "upcaseSelectedKeywords": {
    "title": "Uppercase selected Keywords",
    // "find": "(alpha|beta|epsilon|gamma)",
    "find": "(epsilon)",  // your words to be uppercased 
    "replace": "\\U$1",   // uppercase capture group 1
  }
}
```

And then either assign it to its own keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "alt+y",        // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "findInCurrentFile.upcaseSelectedKeywords",
}
```

and manually trigger it whenever you want to.  Or use it in a macro whenever you trigger <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (save for example):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+s",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        // "interval": 300,  // doesn't appear to be needed here
        "sequence": [
            "findInCurrentFile.upcaseSelectedKeywords",
            "workbench.action.files.save"
        ]
    },
}
```

How to use a command in a `codeAction`:

```
"[javascript]": {                       // will only run when saving a javascript file
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [

        "source.upcaseSelectedKeywords",
        "source.<another findInCurrentFile command you created in the settings"
    ]
}
```